# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS from EC2 wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm migrating my website from a CPanel hosting to Amazon EC2. I'm using Amazon RDS to host my WordPress database.

I followed the following steps:

1. Created a folder with the WordPress files from the old server.
2. Created a database in RDS and uploaded the old site's DB dump.
3. Edited the wp-config.php file to change the parameters to connect to the RDS instance.

While everything worked out fine, except that I'm getting the following error "`Error establishing a database connection`" while I open my site in the browser. I tried changing the security group on RDS and to allow all and also added a user on MySQL with the required permission for the database.

The problem is the connection to RDS is not getting established. I'm able to connect to RDS from my EC2 instance but WordPress is not able to.

My `wp-config.php` looks like:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'db_username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'wordpress-site.something.rds.amazonaws.com:3306');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**EDIT**: I changed my localhost's wp-config.php to point to RDS and the site is working perfectly fine on my localhost. The only problem is the connection issues from EC2.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your AWS settings and have a look to see what ports you have open. IIRC, most are shut, you will probably have to open the port for the DB.

Comment: I have opened all the ports on my security settings just to make sure that the security group is not causing the problem, but I still am not able to connect to RDS through wordpress.

Comment: Perhaps it is the port settings on the wordpress instance.

Answer (score 0):

While using a barebones server, you have to install everything yourself. Please go ahead and check if you have PHP, Apache and mysql installed on your EC2 server, else it will not work!

When you opened ports on the security group, I hope you didn't open all the incoming ports for EC2/RDS as well - Do have a different security group for both of them.

If the site is working from your localhost, it means that the RDS is also accepting incoming connections from anywhere. Ideally, to make the database secure - RDS must only accept incoming connections from one IP (the elastic IP of your EC2 instance)

Cheers!